# What is the term for changing a word due to it being deemed offensive? Our vocabulary is being _____ due to over sensitivity

Tags: single-word-requests

Cockpit is now flight deck and master bedroom is now owners suite.

Comment: I have not yet heard "owner's suite" used. Also, I'm not sure what it's trying to sanitize. If it's trying to sanitize "master" (because it sounds vaguely like a master/slave relationship), then I would say that "owner" isn't really better in any way.

Comment: @Flater I have never heard owner's/owners' suite either, and it strikes me as an awkward phrase due to the uncertainty over where to put the apostrophe. I think that the reason "master bedroom" might be considered un-PC is because it is evocative of sexual inequality, when the man was the master of the house, and not because of having a connotation of slavery.

Comment: @d-mac: I see your point, but that would really apply only in cases when there's a possessive (Master's bedroom, Masters' bedroom). Similarly, a "master key" isn't being gender discriminate either, the "master" refers to a quality of the key, not its owner. As a counterexample, "Master's degree" **does** in fact refer to the owner (and therefore implicitly also their gender) _(That being said, oversensitivity to being PC can of course originate from a wrong understanding of the word, so you might still be right as to the actual reason, but it isn't an objectively correct reason)_

Comment: What sort of word are you looking for here? Is it a good thing? It might be that it's good to change a word which could be offensive. I don't think you think that, but your question needs to be specific. There's a checklist in the tag info: please edit this question to include more information.

Answer (score 2):

**Sanitized**

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanitize

Our vocabulary is being sanitized due to over sensitivity.